# Get local Json 404 issue

Tags: jquery, json

I'm developing a web App and on localhost is working fine.
So now I uploaded the files to web host and when the code loads json it returns a 404 error.
That's the line that I read json:

```
$.getJSON('../json/orthopride.json', function(retorno){
    console.log(retorno)
});
```

Json file is inside a folder called json and this folder is one level before the page that I'm loading.

Comment: so... change the url to where your orthropride.json file is relative to whatever script/page you're running this code from.

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). What is the complete URL it tries to load, and what is the actual URL?

Comment: This isn't about JSON so much as it is about understanding your web server path.  The easiest solution is to look at the developer tools networking tab to see where the page expects `orthopride.json` to be, and either move it on your server or change the path in your `getJSON` request to match what you need.  In the worst case, check your web server logs.

Comment: Your path is wrong, or your webserver is not properly routing the request. It's more likely that the path is simply wrong. Since we can't see your folder structure, there isn't a whole lot we can do...

Comment: Try an absolute path.

Comment: I've tried to access directly
http://www.bilhetto.com.br/ortho/json/orthpride.json
and is returning a 404 too. I'm sure the path is right.. it is possible my host is not able to load json?

Comment: http://www.bilhetto.com.br/ortho/json/orthopride.json  It's a 403.3 error, not a 404 error.  The last link you gave us had an incorrect filename.  That link doesn't.

Comment: Hey @Archer that's right
"The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration."

The Issue is with server not allowing json files.. thanks brother.. if you answear the question i will accept.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you supplied actually gives a 403.3 error, which is a server issue, not a script issue.